# Calling a method from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a method to generate a password in models in Users.rb file. In my view i have a form where only email address filed is there and I want to to add the password to the User attribute before saving it. I have a create method where I create a new user and save it in controller. How do I call the generate password method in the controller?

Comment: Note that models should have a singular filename, ie. `user.rb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it a class method? Call it using `User.generate_password`. Is it an instance method? Call it using `@user.generate_password`, or whatever the instance variable is named.