# Calling a Associated Controller Method Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have 3 models of User, Role and UserRole with their respective controllers as UsersController, RolesController and UserRolesController.

I have a method in the UserRoles controller which I would want to access through the Users controller but I keep having errors as explained below.

I have tried various means of even moving the method `def self.add_roles_to_user(user, role)` from the UsersRoles controller into the UserRole model and call it but I keep having the same error.

I have gone through lots of similar questions and various blogs, including those on this platform such as [Calling a method from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301776/calling-a-method-from-controller), and others but to no good results.

```rb
class UserRole < ApplicationRecord
    # many-to-many association using join table with roles and user
    belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :user_roles
    belongs_to :role, optional: true, inverse_of: :user_roles
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :user_roles, inverse_of: :user
    has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
    # table associations between role and user
    has_many :user_roles, inverse_of: :role
    has_many :users, through: :user_roles
end

class UserRolesController < ApplicationController
  def self.add_roles_to_user(user, role)
    if ! user.nil?
      if role.length > 0
        role.each do |sel_role|
          @u_role = UserRole.new
          @u_role.user_id = user_id
          @u_role.role_id = sel_role.role_id
          @u_role.save
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def create_user
      respond_to do |format|
        if @user.save  
           # add roles
           UserRoles.add_user_roles(params[:user], params[:role])
        end
      end
    end
end
```

I am calling the `add_uer_to_role` method in the User controller when I am adding or creating a new user.

What I have noticed is that I keep getting different errors based on how I call the method.

For example, I expect to have no errors when I call the method like; `UserRoles.add_roles_to_user(params[:user], params[:role])` but it gives the error `NameError (uninitialized constant Users::RegistrationsController::UserRoles):`

Hoping a good samaritan will come to my aid as soon as possible. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a common function, you can define it in application controller and call it. Else you can define in helper.

Please verify [Calling a method from another controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225518/calling-a-method-from-another-controller)

You can use that function as a module and use it:

```rb
# lib/common_stuff.rb
module CommonStuff
  def common_thing
    # code
  end
end

# app/controllers/my_controller.rb
require 'common_stuff'
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include CommonStuff
  # has access to common_thing
end
```

Comment: I have tried all that is possible including the link you asked me to verify above, but still the same error. Kindly study my code well please

Comment: Finally, it's working after moving the methods again to a module. I was having a challenge with the **require statement** but your solution works. Thanks